# Creating custom infowindow in google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps

i am trying to create a custom info window in my google map i find a specific code in the internet but i want to ask if the default library contains a predefined code to do this :

```
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
             google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
                 var l = $('#hook').parent().parent().parent().siblings();
                 for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
                     if ($(l[i]).css('z-index') == 'auto') {
                         $(l[i]).css('border-radius', '16px 16px 16px 16px');

                     }
                 }
             });

          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(long, lat);
                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 'position': point, 'map': map });

                 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function (marker, iLoop) {
                     return function () {
                         infowindow.setContent("<p id='hook'>" + d + "</p>");
                         infowindow.open(map, marker);
                     }
                 })(marker, iLoop));
```

basically what i am doing is going through all parents to reach the pop up is there any other way ?

Comment: I have implemented custom popup after clicking any marker for this i have used ajax in one of my project. Do u need something like that?

Comment: i am asking if i can use the google map library to change my infowindow but can u show me your code it may help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Styling the infowindow is not possible. When using infowindow the only thing you can style is the content that you put inside by giving styles in the tags inside.
You must use infobox instead of infowindow. That is a component that you can style by giving values to the available attributes. Following code is an example

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: theMap,
         draggable: true,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307),
         visible: true
        });

        var boxText = document.createElement("div");
        boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
        boxText.innerHTML = "City Hall, Sechelt<br>British Columbia<br>Canada";

        var myOptions = {
                 content: boxText
                ,disableAutoPan: false
                ,maxWidth: 0
                ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
                ,zIndex: null
                ,boxStyle: { 
                  background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
                  ,opacity: 0.75
                  ,width: "280px"
                 }
                ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
                ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                ,isHidden: false
                ,pane: "floatPane"
                ,enableEventPropagation: false
        };

        var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        ib.open(theMap, marker);
```

Check [here for more](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)

Comment: Of course it is, by having to hack your way through, but there is no easy and documented standard way of doing it. That's why the infobox was created. And I don't like your attitude. If you think I'm wrong give examples and be polite.

Comment: And something else, it's not "my defective infobox" it's from the api.

Answer (score 0):

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content : "<div></div>"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, "domready", function () {
  var popup = $(this.k.contentNode).closest(".gm-style-iw").parent()
    .empty().css({
      width  : "",
      height : "",
      cursor : ""
    })
    .addClass("popup");
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
  infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

You can change `$(this.k.contentNode).closest(".gm-style-iw").parent()` to detect right block in your map. This can be different in major versions of google maps api.

Popup will obtain **left**, **top** and **z-index** automatically when marker changes position.

PS Do not use defective infobox. It's not from the api. This is a third party defective hack written by crooked coders. It "extends" OverlayView

1. It uses many private variables and methods directly. You will obtain a big pain in new major version of api.
2. It forces you to use fixed html included in js.
3. It forces you to include css in your js. I am laughing with "boxStyle", "closeBoxMargin", "closeBoxURL" and others.

Comment: Oh so this is your way of doing it. Great, and if google decides to change the class .gm-style-iw and make it .gm-style-iy you get toasted.

Comment: I like to be fair so I'm going to state why I downvoted: 1. This is a hack and if anything changes in the structure of the markup by google this goes to trash. 2. You don't explain why infobox is defective.

Comment: +1 for puchu, since infobox is not part of the API, any change in the structure of the markup or private functions/variables by google will make your work goes to trash as well. And since it's easier to change some CSS than making changes to the JS, puchu solution is cleaner.